SSH client does not send public key to SSH server
I can't connect to my Ubuntu 22.04 server via SSH from exactly one host. I can connect to that server from other hosts with no problems. But, when I try to connect from that host with: ssh -p 5435 -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 user@my_server.com -vvv
I'm getting:
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.10, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "my_server.com" port 5435
debug3: resolve_host: lookup my_server.com: 5435
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to my_server.com [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 5435.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.10
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.10
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.10 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to my_server.com:5435 as 'user'
debug3: put_host_port: [my_server.com]:5435
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from [my_server.com]:5435
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: have matching best-preference key type ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com, using HostkeyAlgorithms verbatim
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c,kex-strict-c-v00@openssh.com
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,kex-strict-s-v00@openssh.com
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug3: kex_choose_conf: will use strict KEX ordering
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:ChCUrM9ZYCR057q60M84kB6pAQa9bQ8ZEHVuw8g7/p0
debug3: put_host_port: [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:5435
debug3: put_host_port: [my_server.com]:5435
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from [my_server.com]:5435
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host '[my-server.com]:5435' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug1: ssh_packet_send2_wrapped: resetting send seqnr 3
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: ssh_packet_read_poll2: resetting read seqnr 3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:95gTIyyYHXV+UgGYTJiGgC5ulxp3jQoeHmhohQRbIPI
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com=<0>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,keyboard-interactive,password
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
user@my-server.com: Permission denied (publickey).

It seems that the client does not offer any public key to server. There should be Offering public key:... after Authentications that can continue: publickey
I found this thread here: SSH client does not offer public key to SSH server but I didn't get the answer that helps me.
.ssh folder seems to have the right permissions:
user@client:~$ ll .ssh
total 24
drwx------ 2 user user 4096 Oct 13 18:54 ./
drwxr-xr-x 8 user user 4096 Oct 12 12:13 ../
-rw------- 1 user user   96 Sep 14 16:50 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 user user  411 Oct 12 11:42 id_ed25519
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   96 Oct 12 11:42 id_ed25519.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  142 Oct 12 11:45 known_hosts

Also, I have ed25519 enabled in keys:
$ ssh -Q key

ssh-ed25519
ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com
...

My public key is in the server's authorised_keys, I checked that carefully with my local id_ed25519.pub. They are the same.
In the server logs I have:
$ tail -f /var/log/auth.log

Oct 13 19:19:53 my_server sshd[3131]: Connection closed by authenticating user user xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 39810 [preauth]

My ssh version is: OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.10, OpenSSL 3.0.2
What could be the problem? I reinstalled ssh but it does not help. Also generated and uploaded a new key - same error.
Again, I can connect to that server from at least 2 other hosts with the same user.

Please do not cross-post. For the record, another copy is on Ask Ubuntu.

The problem was that in my /etc/ssh/ssh_config on my client, PubkeyAuthentication was set to no.
I thought that if it is set to yes in /etc/ssh/sshd_config it is enough. But it should be yes on both.
The answer is not mine, I've got help in AskUbuntu from Kos and Fritz: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1529881/ssh-client-does-not-offer-public-key-to-ssh-server
I'm sorry for double posting, I didn't know that media is the same.

Maybe you had good intentions, probably; but since I noticed you have posted the question on multiple SE sites and you've actually got the solution from a fellow user on Ask Ubuntu, I cannot fight the impression that posting the solution here as your own is inelegant.

That's correct, I've got the answer in Ask Ubuntu. But I didn't know that they share same media. And because I posted on both, decided to post the answer here so the people will know that I fond the answer. I will edit my answer.

For future reference, nearly all StackExchange sites have a box labeled StackExchange next to the hamburger at the left of the top nav bar (just below your browser's URL bar if any) and a column headed "Stack Exchange Network" in the bottom nav area

First you shouldn't have to include the "-i" parameter. Your keys are at the right place unless your system is configured otherwise.
Then it seems that your ssh -vvv logs is partial. When I do this I have a lot more info.
So many possibilities..

Version : openssh must be > 6.5
Configuration : Some ciphers ed25519 must not be deactivated..

That's all for now. If you have more info, I may modify this answer.
Versions :

my open ssh is: OpenSSH_8.9p1, I edited my question and now I added full -vvv output.
